# KafkaProducer send a list of messages or break list into individual messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is it okay to batch 100 messages into a single object and send those objects to kafka or should I split those 100 messages into individual messages and then put them in kafka
Say for example, I have an object that contains a List. I can put 100 strings in that list and send the object to kafka. Is it better to do it that way or should i split the list of strings and send individual strings to kafka instead 
What are some pros and cons to the above approaches

Answer (score 0):

Batching is always good when async processing, until you need to partially process the batch in case of errors.
If you are processing an order and the list of 100 are the items. send them together, as they will be processed together. If you are sending 100 orders, and will process the independently, process them one by one, as the error in one order should not block the others.
As for message sizes, kafka has some message size limits, but these are configurable.
Definitively you need to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send a huge message that is more than the max.message.bytes configuration of your kafka broker(let's assume you can't change it). You break it down and put it back together at the consumer side.

This would require some work around the limitations of kafka deployment as of now. For e.g
 Should your consumer process all these 100 strings as if they were one batch? when should your consumer decide to commit the offsets for these messages? Is your consumer processing idempotent? Do you have one consumer or multiple consumer instances? what if the 100 strings were split across 5 partitions? which consumer gets which subset of these 100 strings?

An approach is to create 100 messags all with the same batch id like so

```
  (batch1:message1, batch1:message2, batch1:message3)
```

On the consumer side collect all these messages with the same key

```
  (batch1: (message1, message2, message3))
```

But, how would you know when the batch ends? does the sequence message1, message2, message3 matter?

So you do something like this

```
  (batch1:message1of3, batch1:message2of3, batch1:messsage3of3)
```

Now what if you received message1of3 and message2of3 but not message3of3? how long do you wait for it?

As you can see, at each step there are multiple ways to go about this and you will have to make choices right for your problem. Perhaps, you will use timeouts, perhaps in your case batches are interleaved like this

```
  (batch1:message1of3, batch2:message2of5, batch1:message2of3...)
```

Expect to make some compromises. With Kafka your consumer group is guaranteed to receive all messages, and while it's running, any consumer is assigned one or more partitions(meaning a single partition is not assigned to more than one consumer at the same time). Kafka will also assign messages with the same key to the same partition. With these two properties in mind you can design a system that can consume messages in batches with some obvious trade-offs and limitations.